# Blender 2.9; render view is showing transparent spots

Tags: modeling

Why is the default image, showing this when I render? I only opened blender, and then made it render the image, without changing any options.

Thanks

[image: blender render]

Comment: Check if your GPU fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and update your graphics driver.

Comment: I have Intel HD graphics 520, 2GB of vram

Comment: The graphics driver can be downloaded from [Intel's website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/en/product/88355).